Dart code is being blocked during assignment operation to map
The code flow stops moving forward when it encounters the assignment statement. it doesn't show any any error nor does the code exit,it just stops there. it works fine on flutter web though
 Future<(double, Map<DateTime, int>)> suppliercalc() async {
    final user = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser;
    final orderef = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('orders');
    final date = DateTime.now();
    double monthlysales = 0;
    final thismonth = DateTime(date.year, date.month, 1, 0, 0, 0);

    final Map<DateTime, int> linegraphdata = {};

    final userid = "/userdetails/${user!.uid}";

    final docs = await orderef
        .where('timestamp', isGreaterThan: thismonth)
        .where('supplier_id', isEqualTo: userid)
        .where('delivered', isEqualTo: true)
        .get();
    final docdata = docs.docs;
    for (var eachdoc in docdata) {
      Timestamp stamp = eachdoc['timestamp'];
      DateTime eachdate = stamp.toDate();
      eachdate = DateTime(eachdate.year, eachdate.month, eachdate.day);
      monthlysales = monthlysales + eachdoc['total'];
      if (eachdate.isBefore(DateTime(date.year, date.month, date.day))) {
        DateTime edate = DateTime(eachdate.year, eachdate.month, eachdate.day);

        if (linegraphdata.containsKey(edate)) {
          linegraphdata[edate] =
              linegraphdata[edate]! + eachdoc['total'] as int;
        } else {
          log('before');
          linegraphdata[edate] = eachdoc['total'] as int;
          log('after');
        }
      }
    }

    return (monthlysales, linegraphdata);
  }

what this code does is to create a map with each date having the sum of the 'total',
but the code stops after showing the first log('before')
i also tried using the addEntries() and putifAbsent() but they too paused at that point

You say "it doesn't show any any error", but are you sure that you don't have some catch or error handler somewhere that is silently swallowing exceptions?  You should adjust your log statements to log useful details; for example: log('before ${eachdoc['total']}');

@jamesdlin  i fixed the problem, it was beacuse of casting the 'eachdoc' to int

@jamesdlin then please update your question or close it

so ,i figured out the problem,it was because i was casting 'eachdoc' to int while it was double.
